# Segmentation fault while calculating the intersection of two sets

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, segmentation-fault, set

I need to find the intersection of two arrays and print out the number of elements in the intersection of the two arrays. I must also account for any duplicate elements in both the arrays. So, I decide to take care of the duplicate elements by converting the two arrays into sets and then take the intersection of both the sets. However, I encounter a segmentation fault when I run my code. I'm not sure where this occurs, any way to fix this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
using namespace std;
int NumberofElementsInIntersection (int a[], int b[], int n, int m ){
        // Your code goes here
        int i=0,j=0,count=0;
        set<int> s1,s2;
        vector<int> v;
        vector<int>::iterator it;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            s1.insert(a[i]);
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
            s2.insert(b[i]);
       it=set_intersection(s1.begin(),s1.end(),s2.begin(),s2.end(),v.begin());
       return (it-v.begin());
}

int main(){
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int b[] = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    cout<<NumberofElementsInIntersection(a,b,6,5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your vector is empty, so this will try to write values to invalid indexes. You probably want a `back_inserter`.

Comment: Since `v` is empty, `v.begin()` returns the same as `v.end()` which can't be referenced. You need to resize the vector `v` or use something like [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter). I also recommend you read more about [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_intersection` does not allocate memory: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

You need a `vector` with some space. Change `vector<int> v;` to `vector<int> v(n+m);`

https://ideone.com/NvoZBu

Answer (score 3):

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

Your vector iterator does not resize the vector to add new elements. You should have used a `back_inserter` instead.

```
//also needs #include <iterator>
int NumberofElementsInIntersection (int a[], int b[], int n, int m ){
        // Your code goes here
        int i=0;
        set<int> s1,s2;
        vector<int> v;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            s1.insert(a[i]);
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
            s2.insert(b[i]);
       set_intersection(s1.begin(),s1.end(),s2.begin(),s2.end(),back_inserter(v));
       return v.size();
}
```

Comment: Make sure you `#include <iterator>`.

Comment: I did try this, but it showed me an error: no operator "=" matches these operands -- operand types are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>> = std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>C/C++(349)

Comment: @SreyaSalil Ok, I actually tried it this time. Fixed.

Comment: @dratenik `std::set<int> s1(a, a + n); std::set<int> s2(b, b + m);` -- Then the `for` loops are not necessary.,

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to provide a std:: back_inserter(v). No preallocation is required, but it is helpful from an optimization standpoint. See example in

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection